# Connecting More than one device ussing gameKit framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, gamekit

I am using `GameKit` framework for bluetooth connectivity between devices and then sending and receiving data.My problem is how to connect more than one device using `Gamekit`.I spend almost one week in searching on internet, but got nothing except questions posted with no answer.

Please suggest me that how can I connect  more than one device or any link or tutorial which I can follow.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Apple documentation its very helpful.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: thanks but not getting actually what to do.I will again read it.